# onClick CSS Background Change

Tags: css, background, onclick

Edits: Changed the function name to swap, and put the onClick function as part of the DIV element, not working still.

I have read several topics on this issue, tried each different code, went to W3Schools for the most correct code. I want to change the background of the parent DIV when someone clicks on either it or the image contained within it.

The following is in the HEAD section of my HTML

```
<script type="javascript/text">
  <!--
    function swap() {
      document.getElementById("links").style.backgroundImage = "url('middle_background.png')";
    }
  -->
</script>
```

The following is in the body:

```
<div class="nav" id="links" onClick="swap();">
  <img src="images/links.png" alt="Links" />
</div>
```

This is the CSS in a separate file:

```
.nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background: url(images/nav_buttons.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 111px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

I assure you the image: middle_backgrounds is in the root folder. (A copy is also in the images folder.)

Comment: You shouldn't name the function `switch`. That's a reserved word in JavaScript.

Comment: Do not use `switch` as function name its pre-defined keyword

Comment: Check and see what console errors you're getting.

Comment: I looked at Inspect Element and switched to Console, clicked on JS tab and nothing came up.

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick at parent div instead of img tag. Body would be look below

`<div class="nav" id="links" onClick="changeBackgroundImage();" >
<img src="images/links.png" alt="Links" />
</div>`

Comment: `switch` is not a valid function name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
function switch1() {
  document.getElementById("links").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')";
}
```

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background-image: url(images/nav_buttons.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 111px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="links"  onClick="switch1();">
  <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" alt="Links" />
</div>
```

Comment: Then how can I override the existing CSS rule?

Comment: @BrentWalker No. I confused with img tag and background-image property... It will work for you

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes that used to be the problem which required a lot more code. I just took out the CSS background property from the .Nav and the onClick function isn't loading up the background still.

Answer (score 0):

I tested its working...

don't use function switch() because that is predefined , change the function name

```
    <div class="nav" id="links"><img src="Images/progress.gif" alt="Links" onclick="change();" /></div>

    function change() {

 $('#links').css('background-image', 'url(Images/progress.gif)');


           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but this managed to solve my problem. Just by changing the urls to match my images and locations. Thank you!

```js
function switch1() {
  document.getElementById("links").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')";
}
```

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background-image: url(images/nav_buttons.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 111px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="links"  onClick="switch1();">
  <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" alt="Links" />
</div>
```